# ¿Cómo restaurar BD en MYSQL desde JAVA?

Tags: java, mysql, cmd

¿Cómo puedo restaurar una Base de Datos en `MySQL`?, ya tengo el `respaldo.sql` donde esta toda la estructura de mi base de datos, el problema es que no he encontrado la forma para hacerlo desde JAVA.
Tengo esta parte de código:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
                    "C:\\xampp\\mysql\\bin\\mysql -u root -p bd\"-e 'source C:\\Users\\proyecto\\eclipse-workspace\\mysql\\respaldo.sql'\"");
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
            String line = null;
            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
            in.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: ¿Por qué quieres hacerlo desde Java? ¿Por qué no directamente?

Comment: Necesito desarrollar un programa en JAVA que me haga el respado de una BD MySQL

Comment: Con lo que estás intentando, puede que te falle el tema de la redirección que haces al ejecutar (<), ya que este redireccionamiento es sintaxis de la shell y el proceso que intentas ejecutar no lo ejecuta la shell sino la máquina virtual de Java. Si ves que eso puede ser un fallo prueba con "-e 'source infocentro.sql'" en lugar de "< infocentro.sql"

Comment: Ya hice los cambios que me dijiste, pero ahora se queda corriendo el programa y no me realiza ningún cambio en mi BD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya logre corregir el codigo, me quedo de esta forma:

```
public class mysqldumoSubir {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:/xampp/mysql/bin/mysql --user=root --password= bd");

            OutputStream os = p.getOutputStream();
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("respaldo.sql");
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1000];

            int leido = fis.read(buffer);
            while (leido > 0) {
                os.write(buffer, 0, leido);
                leido = fis.read(buffer);
            }

            os.flush();
            os.close();
            fis.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: te funiona como esperabas? si es asi da por resuelta tu pregunta